# JS vs Python byte array encoding

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, byte

I am trying to convert a byte array into a string and then send it over a socket to a remote server. I have successfully prototyped the code in **Python** and am trying to migrate it to **Javascript**.

For some reason, there is a discrepancy in the last character between the two languages.

**Python Code**

```
def make_checksum(data):
    num = 0x00
    for num2 in data:
        num = (num + num2) & 0xFF
    return num

data = [0x56, 0x54, 0x55, 0x3E, 0x28, 0x00, 0x08, 
        0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0]
message = bytearray(data + [make_checksum(data)])
```

**Javascript**

```
function checksum(data) {
    let res = 0x00
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        res = (res + data[i]) & 0xFF
    }
    return String.fromCharCode(res)
}

let data = new Int8Array([0x56, 0x54, 0x55, 0x3E, 0x28, 0x00,
           0x08, 0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0])
let message = String.fromCharCode(...data) + checksum(data)
```

I think this might have something to do with the difference between *ascii* and *UTF*.

Comment: Should the javascript be doing `checksum(data)` instead of `checksum(0xC0)`?  Should the python be doing `bytearray(data + [make_checksum(data)])`?

Comment: If `message` is bytes, you shouldn’t represent it with a string in JavaScript. Leave it as a `Uint8Array`.

Comment: do we talk about node or about browser JS here? You can't represent any byte array as string because not every byte array is valid unicode.

Comment: I don't know how JavaScript stores integers (or strings, for that matter), but I notice that `0xC0` is the only value in that array that is 1: negative if signed but positive if unsigned, and 2: not a valid ASCII byte.  This might or might not be relevant.

Comment: @mgilson It was a mistake, it should have been `checksum(data)`, I just fixed it

Comment: @Ryan I need to post it to a server as a string, how can I leave it as an array?

Comment: @Lux Everything here is in **node** and I am using the `net` module to create a socket.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski: How are you posting it to a server? Please show that code.

Comment: @Ryan using stream.write(data)

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski: `stream.write` accepts a buffer. `Buffer.concat([Buffer.from([0x56, 0x54, 0x55, 0x3E, 0x28, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0]), checksum(data)])`, where `checksum` also returns a `Buffer`.

Comment: Works fine. [Python 119](https://ideone.com/kFIUWg), [Node.js 119](https://ideone.com/MAJpMC)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153837/discussion-between-dov-benyomin-sohacheski-and-ryan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [@Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) I was able to solve the issue by using a `Buffer` instead of an unsigned array.

**Code**

```
function checksum(data) {
    let res = 0x00
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        res = (res + data[i]) & 0xFF
    }
    return Buffer.from([res])
}

let data = Buffer.from([0x56, 0x54, 0x55, 0x3E, 0x28, 0x00, 
                  0x08, 0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x4F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
console.log(Buffer.concat([data, checksum(data)]))
```